# javascript validation not working on page with multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

The javascript is not validating the fields on the "Coupon" form. If a field is left empty it should send them to an error page. As it is now, you can leave first and last name empty and and enter your email address to get to the coupon. Only the email address form is validating. Below is the code I currently have. The form is the namath-coupon-form about half of the way down the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validate-coupon-form()
{

   if (document.subscribeForm.First_Name.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter your First Name");
      document.subscribeForm.First_Name.focus();
      return false;
   }

   if (document.subscribeForm.Last_Name.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter your Last Name");
      document.subscribeForm.Last_Name.focus();
      return false;
   }

   if (document.subscribeForm.Email Address.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter your Email Address");
      document.subscribeForm.Email Address.focus();
      return false;
   }

   return( true );

}


</script>



        <div class="namath-coupon-form-header">

        <form class="namath-coupon-form" action="http://cl.exct.net/subscribe.aspx?lid=7549071" name="subscribeForm" method="post" onSubmit="return validate-coupon-form();">
            <input type="hidden" name="thx" value="http://www.namathproducts.com/get-coupons-thank-you">
            <input type="hidden" name="err" value="http://www.namathproducts.com/get-coupons-error">
            <input type="hidden" name="MID" value="10692030">
            <input type="hidden" name="Email Type" value="HTML" checked>
            <input type="hidden" name="BU_Namath" value="TRUE" checked>
            <input type="hidden" name="SubAction" value="sub_add_update" checked>
            <label for="FirstName">
                <span>First Name *</span>
                <input type="text" class="required" name="First_Name" id="FirstName" >
            </label><br>

            <label for="LastName">
                <span>Last Name *</span>
            <input type="text" class="required" name="Last_Name" id="LastName" >
            </label><br>

            <label for="EmailAddress">
                <span>Email *</span>
                <input type="text" class="required" name="Email Address" id="EmailAddress" placeholder="name@example.com" >
            </label><br>

            <label>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="Submit" value="GET COUPON">
            </label>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The form in the header and near the footer are validating.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should reduce the code to the minimum that displays the issue, e.g. tens of thousands of lines of library code are added but the function in question doesn't use any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be ignoring a lot of errors. Hyphens aren't valid in ECMAScript identifiers, so you must remove them from function and variable names (e.g. change *validate-coupon-form* to *validateCouponForm*).

You have three forms with the name *subscribeForm*, so *document.subscribeForm* will return a collection of all three forms and `document.subscribeForm.First_Name.value` should throw an error.

To avoid that, change the listener to

```
<form ... name="subscribeForm" onSubmit="return validateCouponForm(this);" ...>
```

so that a reference to the form is passed directly to the function, then in the function use *form* to reference the form

```
function validateCouponForm(form) {

  if (form.First_Name.value == "") {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```